# Do contracts deploy their imported dependency contracts? Or do they point to live, already deployed versions?

Tags: contract-development, truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-deployment

This is a very newbie question about deploying contracts with imported dependencies.

I'm using Chainlink's `AggregatorV3Interface` and `SafeMath` from openzeppelin.

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

I've noticed `truffle compile` spits out the ABI's for both `AggregatorV3Interface` and `SafeMath` along with Contract I wrote myself. Why does Truffle do that?

When I deploy my contract, are the imported dependency contracts deployed also?

Or does my Contract reference the `AggregatorV3Interface` already deployed to mainnet by Chainlink?

Likewise, does my contract just reference the `SafeMath` contract already deployed by OpenZeppelin? Or does Truffle deploy that too?

I noticed that on Remix, when using `SafeMath` or `AggregatorV3Interface` you use import with an absolute URL to Github. So, it was a little confusing as to why Truffle compiles the imported contracts too.

Comment: it depends on how you implement it, there are 2 types of libraries Embedded and linked. you can read more about it here. Most of us use embedded, which means the code of the library is included in your byte code when you compile the contract and will be deployed with.
https://medium.com/coinmonks/all-you-should-know-about-libraries-in-solidity-dd8bc953eae7

Comment: if you using the latest version of solidity you dont need safe math anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truffle compiles everything, including those imported.
The imported SafeMath is included in your contract, and only your contract is distributed.
It refers to the deployed contract by setting the deployed contract address as an argument of AggregatorV3Interface.